# Convert large TIFF to MBTiles

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles

I have a large number of compressed GeoTIFF (600,000, Orthophotos) which I want to convert into an MBTiles (into a file).

I have summarized the TIFFs via GDAL in a VRT file but QGIS is not able to create an MBFile from it. GDAL_Translate somehow doesn't get any further either.

Has anyone ever processed similar amounts of data and maybe has a tip for me? I work with Windows if that is somehow important.

Comment: please add the error messages

Comment: there are none, qgis just crashes without a message.

Comment: What parameters did you use? Minzoom seems to default to 0 https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html which means that for the first tile GDAL should mosaic all 600,000 orthos into one tile. Have you tried to start from a bigger minzoom value? Test with small areas first by using the -te option of gdal_translate.

Comment: what operating system

Comment: is use this command with gdal:
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 12288 -of mbtiles -co TILE_FORMAT=JPEG -co QUALITY=85 Pfad\322.vrt D:\322.mbtiles.

operating system is Windows with the OSGeo4W installation
I split the data into 8 VRTs to later merge them back into a DB using SQLite. But GDAL remains at 30%. Waited over 10h.

Comment: How many gigabytes and total pixel dimensions are your 600 000 orthophotos? Even if you divided it into 8 vrt's, that amount of data could take days to process in my experience.

Comment: It's about 400 GB. I started the calculation process on another PC and it seems that it actually seems to be a matter of time. A VRT with all data has been calculating for 5 days and is at 20%. So it must be patient and hope that the PC does not crash. Nevertheless, I would be interested in experience if someone has already successfully calculated a similar amount of data.

Comment: tippecanoe preforms really good https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe